# condition not referencing the second rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html index.php?page=$1&title=$2

RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html index.php?profile=$1&staffName=$2
```

Hi,

Basically I am trying to use mod_rewrite to make it so that when the variable id is page, it references the first rule and if the profile is isset then use the second rule.

But when I try it, the pages are fine but the profile pages are breaking as the mod_rewrite is trying to use the first rule and breaks.

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thing is that mod_rewrite parses the requested URL according to the first statement and tranforms it according to the rules stated in the second one. But your initial URL-patterns are the same, so it can't distinguish them.

Also, forego the backslash of the file-extension-point ... I think that causes trouble.

Also you can test your rules very comfortable with [this tool](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/).

'RewriteRule (.*)/(.*).html index.php?page=$1&title=$2' for example works just fine and will transform /a/b.html to index.php?page=a&title=b.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate your input. I understand now why it doesn't work, but any idea how I can make it work with three different rewrite rules as I have another one as will require three different paramaters eg. index.php?page=, index.php?profile=, index.php?footer= . Thanks for all the help

Comment: you need to give examples for what should be translated to what

Comment: Cool thanks, here we go index.php?page=1&title=home to page/1/home.html   the same again for index.php?profile=1&staffname=naomi to profile/1/naomi.html    these are the examples, also if you know a way to get round referencing the id of the row in the url that would be awesome.  Thanks

Comment: "index.php?page=1&title=home to page/1/home.html" then you don't use mod_rewrite but reloacte by PHP. mod_rewrite you use to turn beautiful URL "page/1/home.html" to ugly URL "index.php?page=1&title=home".